# how to match a whitespace in a bash variable

Tags: bash

According to the man page, the string to the right of `=~` is treated as an extended regular expression. I've tried the following things to match an "ok" surrounded by whitespace on either side, but nothing is working. Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Maybe there's a shell option that needs to be enabled?

```
if ! [[ $RESULT =~ \s"ok"\s ]]; then

if ! [[ $RESULT =~ [:space:]"ok"[:space:] ]]; then

if ! [[ $RESULT =~ [ \t\r\n\v\f]"ok"[ \t\r\n\v\f] ]]; then
```

NOTE: self answered question below.

Answer (score 12):

Ok, it turns out one needs `[[:space:]]` instead of `[:space:]`. The following works:

```
if ! [[ $RESULT =~ [[:space:]]"ok"[[:space:]] ]]; then
```

Comment: That is because `[:space:]` itself is just *a character class consisting of `:`, `s`, `p`, `a`, `c`, `e`*. The intended special meaning of `[:space:]` and alike is only available inside a true character class, — otherwise it would not be possible to combine several of them in a single class if any of them would create a class by its own.

Comment: @AntonSamsonov ah! i see. Good to know.